# Is there a way to add fractions in dateadd

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I was surprised to see this query gives two columns with identical values

```sql
select 
    dateadd(hour, -1.5, GETUTCDATE()) as OneAndAHalf, 
    dateadd(hour, -1, GETUTCDATE()) as One
```

Is it possible to use dateadd in this way, or am I going to have to calculate the datetime in code?

Comment: Of course, it is possible. You can add 90 minutes or 60 minutes

Comment: per the docs number is an integer so you would need a more granular date part https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: 0.5 of an hour is not a fraction of a second?

Answer (score 4):

According to [the Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) the answer is no.  You cannot add a non-integer value (either as a literal or as an expression) as 'number' in the DATEADD function.

As other members mentioned: switch the DATEPART to an appropriate interval (like minutes) and use that instead.  To add "fractions of a second" you could use 'millisecond' which adds thousandth's of a second.

```
select getdate()
union all
select dateadd(millisecond,100, getdate())
```

```
(No column name)
2021-08-06 11:15:04.260
2021-08-06 11:15:04.360
```

> Syntax SQL
>
> DATEADD (datepart , ***number*** , date )
>
> ***number*** An expression that can **resolve to an int** that DATEADD adds to a
> datepart of date. DATEADD accepts user-defined variable values for
> number. DATEADD will truncate a specified number value that has a
> decimal fraction. It will not round the number value in this
> situation.

Answer (score 2):

Multiply your increment by 60 and add it as minutes (or multiply them by 3600 and add it as seconds)

```
select 
    dateadd(minute, -1.5 * 60, GETUTCDATE()) as OneAndAHalf, 
    dateadd(minute, -1 * 60, GETUTCDATE()) as One

select 
    dateadd(second, -1.5 * 3600, GETUTCDATE()) as OneAndAHalf, 
    dateadd(second, -1 * 3600, GETUTCDATE()) as One
```